# How to modify order-form.tpl with mail options opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart, admin

i want to add an option with select control about send mail to customer or not when admin add new order or edit the existing order. and i have trouble with using API. 
i added this :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-mailcontrol"><?php echo $entry_email; ?><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_shipping; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" </span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="mailcontrol" id="input-mailcontrol" class="form-control">

                <?php if ($mailcontrol) { ?>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                        <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                        <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and also these:

```
$('#tab-customer input[name=\'mailcontrol\']').val(item['mailcontrol']);
```

and i added everywhere that i see the customer fields.
but still i can not reach that data on the api side. always having same error about there is no such data. 
thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem with custom fields, i added radio controls with custom fields and checked this custom fields about send mail or not send.

catalog-model-checkout line 605.

> $mail_control=$this->db->query("SELECT * from `order` where order_id='".(int)$order_id."'");
>   foreach($mail_control->rows as $m){
>   $t=$m['custom_field'];}

if (!$this->model_payment_amazon_checkout->isAmazonOrder($order_info['order_id']) && strpos($t,"3")){  // 3= custom_field_id